# Working with Pandas - Max, Min, First, Last

Tags: python, pandas, candlestick-chart

I have a pandas dataframe in python that is stock prices by the minute.  I want to use it to create a "3 minute" chart.  To do that I need to work backwards across the dataframe and consolidate it as follows.

Open is the first "open" value in the set of 3
High is the max value in the set of 3
Min is the min value in the set of 3
Close is the las "close value in the set of 3

I need help with the right sytanx to:

1. create sets of 3
2. pull out the values that I need and put into a new dataframe

Here is what I have so far but it isn't working.  I'm doing something wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
stock = 'SPY'
api = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/'+stock+'/chart/1d' 
df = pd.read_json(api)
df['stock'] = stock
df1= df[['stock', 'label', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']]


dct = {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min',
       'close': 'last', 'stock': 'first', 'label': 'last'}

(df1.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df1.label, errors='coerce'))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3min'))
    .agg(dct)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: sorry!  I stopped now :)   Didn't realize what was going on

Comment: Can you double check a couple outputs for me, I believe your first entry in `high` is incorrect (should be 283.58) and I believe your first entry in `close` is incorrect (should be 283.58), and I think all of your times are incorrect, since they should represent each 3 minute window.

Comment: I think the entries were correct when you first posted the question, but your edit changed them.

Comment: Correct.  My mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `resample`:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['label'], errors='coerce'))\
  .resample('3T')\
  .agg({'stock': 'first',
        'label': 'last',
        'open': 'first', 
        'high': 'max', 
        'low': 'min',
        'close': 'last'})\
  .reset_index(drop=True)[['stock','label','open','high','low','close']]
```

Output:

```
  stock     label    open     high     low    close
0   SPY  09:32 AM  283.44  283.580  283.32  283.580
1   SPY  09:35 AM  283.54  283.690  283.54  283.675
2   SPY  09:38 AM  283.66  283.795  283.48  283.545
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.Grouper` with `agg`:

```
dct = {'open': 'first', 'high': 'max', 'low': 'min',
       'close': 'last', 'stock': 'first', 'label': 'last'}

(df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.label, errors='coerce'))
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='3min'))
    .agg(dct)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
     open     high     low    close stock     label
0  283.44  283.580  283.32  283.580   SPY  09:32 AM
1  283.54  283.690  283.54  283.675   SPY  09:35 AM
2  283.66  283.795  283.48  283.545   SPY  09:38 AM
```

Comment: Thanks.  Getting an error OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 10:00:00

Comment: Sounds like you have some bad data in your `label` column.

Comment: Here is exactly how I'm trying to use it.  If I send to csv I don't see any null values or bad data.  Any thoughts?  Thanks for such a quick answer!